# Change Profile submission confirmation FROM email

Tags: profile, email, smtp, shortcode

I have a standalone profile that is embedded on a WordPress page using a shortcode. I have set up email notifications in the advanced settings of the profile for when a submission occurs. I receive the email fine, but I would like to change the FROM email address it's sent from, usually send from the default one. I could not find any setting to override that. Any idea how to achieve that, please? Thanks

Comment: The help text of the field says `The first email address listed will be used as the FROM address in the notifications.` but i doubt it works that way. Worth testing though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a [extension](https://github.com/pradpnayak/profilefromaddress) that allows one to select from an address and message template for notification when a profile is submitted.

It needs a [patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/29441) to be applied to make it work. The PR should be merged in 5.72 version.